# PHP TimeZone incorrect

Tags: php, apache, timezone

I'm on WAMP running Apache Version 2.4.4  PHP Version  5.4.12.

I have this code to output and test the time / time zone.

```
<?php
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
echo "<br>Script time zone is $script_tz, ini timezone is " . ini_get('date.timezone');
echo "<br>Date Time now is " . date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

echo "<br>Script time zone is $script_tz, ini timezone is " . ini_get('date.timezone');
echo "<br>Date Time now is " . date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
?>
```

The output is as follows

```
Script time zone is UTC, ini timezone is UTC
Date Time now is 03/09/2014 05:16:21 pm
Script time zone is Australia/Melbourne, ini timezone is UTC
Date Time now is 03/10/2014 04:16:21 am
```

However the current time in Melbourne is 09:16 am, and not 04:16am! 
What can i do to correct this?

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Try `Australia/Brisbane` instead some servers does not support that time zone; but this time zone offset is same as Melbroune

Comment: I'm running this on localhost, local WAMP server.
Using the same code above i changed it to Australia/Brisbane

Now it says:

Script time zone is UTC, ini timezone is UTC
Date Time now is 03/09/2014 05:41:18 pm
Script time zone is Australia/Brisbane, ini timezone is UTC
Date Time now is 03/10/2014 03:41:18 am

This is still incorrect as Melbourne is now 9:41am

Comment: What's your system time? Maybe your default system time is not correctly adjusted

Comment: Good question. My system is currently set as Malaysian time. I'll check this out and change the system time later when i get back and let u know the results.